# CSV Import to multiple tables - speed consideration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, file-upload

I have an app that will take sales made available to vendors at Whole Foods and process the daily sales data by store and item.  All the parent information is stored in one downloaded CSV with about 10,000 lines per month.

The importing process checks for new stores before importing the sale information.

I don't know how to track 'time' of processes in ruby and rails but i was wondering if it would be 'faster' to process one line at a time to each table or to process the file for one table (stores) and then to the other table (sales)

If it matters in anything, new stores are not often added though stores might be closed (and the import checks for that as well), so the scan through the stores might only add a few new entries whereas every row of the csv is added to the sales.

If this isn't appropriate - I apologize - still working out the kinks of the rules

Comment: 10k rows csv is nothing to worry about even having the less efficient  solution possible :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko What level of rows should I start worrying about things like this then?

Comment: I mean you are right to worry about efficiency always - it is definitely a good thing to do. But I'd say at least few hundreds thousands is a right time. But I'll add an answer in a moment with some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to processing data with Ruby the memory consumption is what you should be concerned about.

With csv processing in Ruby, the best you can do is reading line by line:

```
file = CSV.open("data.csv")
while line = file.readline
  # do stuff
end
```

This way no matter how many lines are in the file, there always be only single one (+ previous processed one) loaded into memory at a time - GC will collect processed lines as your program executes. This way is almost no-memory consumptive + it will speed up the parsing process, too.

> i was wondering if it would be 'faster' to process one line at a time
>   to each table or to process the file for one table (stores) and then
>   to the other table (sales)

I would go with one line at a time to each table.

Comment: i actually use eachline in my code.  My concern was is it 'more efficient' to loop through once to look for new records in one table and then loop through again to enter different data from every row - or to perform both actions at the same time on each row.  Perhaps your comment that at 10K lines it won't really have that much impact is the answer for that question

Comment: @MageeWorld I would definitely go and make it in single loop rather than in two, it is going to be done anyway, so why bothering with two loops? Just put the whole logic while processing each line and that would be good.

Comment: @Andrey-Dineko Thanks for that - when i was running my tests I ran them separately - but in general i do combine them (I have another application that makes multiple calls to online sources for diffferent json files and processes them to different tables, all dependent on eariler data and run that in one loop itself)